# Get rid of if statements to improve code design

Tags: java, if-statement, strategy-pattern

How can I improve the design of the code below:

```
class Foo {
   public Configuration configure() {
      return new Configuration().withPropertyA().withPropertyB();
   }
}

class Configuration{


   private boolean propertyA = false;
   private boolean propertyB = false;

   public Configuration withPropertyA() {
       this.propertyA = true;
       return this;
   }

    public Configuration withPropertyB() {
       this.propertyB = true;
       return this;
   }

   public boolean hasPropertyA() {
      return this.propertyA;
   }

   public boolean hasPropertyB() {
      return this.propertyB;
   }

   ...
}

class Client{

public void someMethod(Configuration config) {
   if (config.hasPropertyA() {
      doStuffA();
   }
   if (config.hasPropertyB() {
      doStuffB();
   }
   //...
}

}
```

I.e., the Configuration class holds some flags for the caller (`Client`) that tell to the caller which "things" need to be configured. The Client knows what to do for each of the flags if they are set. I want to get rid of the if statement in `Client` as well as of the concept of simply setting boolean flags in the `Configuration` instance. Can you suggest a more "generic" and object oriented approach to this?

kind regards

Comment: Code optimization is generally off-topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the **Strategy pattern**.
Each If becomes a Strategy, which implements doStuff, with its own logic. When a property (A, B...) is set, you add the strategy to the list. You simply need to loop on the strategies and execute them, without any ifs:

```
public class Foo  {
    public Configuration configure() {
        return new Configuration().withPropertyA().withPropertyB();
    }
}

class Configuration {
    Set<StuffStrategy> strategies = new HashSet<StuffStrategy>();

    public Configuration withPropertyA() {
        strategies.add(new PropertyAStrategy());
        return this;
    }

    public Configuration withPropertyB() {
        strategies.add(new PropertyBStrategy());
        return this;
    }

    public void executeStrategies() {
        for (StuffStrategy strategy : strategies) {
            strategy.doStuff();
        }
    }
}

interface StuffStrategy {
    public void doStuff();
}
class PropertyAStrategy implements StuffStrategy {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
    }
}

class PropertyBStrategy implements StuffStrategy {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
    }
}

class Client {
    public void someMethod(Configuration config) {
        config.executeStrategies();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you can find a more OO approach than what you currenly do especially if you can have more parameters, indeed this is somehow the well know design pattern [Builder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), the best you can do is finishing implementing this pattern properly by making your object `Configuration` immutable from outside only your builder class should be able to create an instance of `Configuration`. Your builder should be a mutable static inner class with a `build()` method that returns an immutable `Configuration` instance.

Comment: I think @Alex provided a clean object oriented approach for this. However, I'll give you an up-vote for the builder hint. thx

Comment: @user1291235 even if it seems to be "clean" as you said, it is not flexible at all, what will you do if your needs change a little bit and you have to support cases where you have both property A and B or you have A but not B, your code will then be a nightmare to maintain

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you are writing a pitfall

try using in that case something more flexible in the design.... like an enumerator...
take a look at this:

## Example:

```
public class Foo {
    public Configuration configure() {
    return new Configuration(Config.A);
    }
}

class Configuration {

enum Config{
A,B, NONE}

    private Config propertyConfig = Config.NONE;

    public Configuration(Config a) {
    propertyConfig=a;
    }


    public Config getConfig() {
    return this.propertyConfig;
    }

    ...
}

class Client {

    public void someMethod(Configuration config) {
       switch (config.getConfig()) {
    case A:
        System.out.println("a config");
        break;
    case B:
        System.out.println("b config");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    // ...
}

}
```

Comment: So you replaced `if` statements with a `switch-case`. How is that better / different?

Comment: Are you aware that a switch case if faster than a if else, omitting the fact of the design in the code...

Comment: Perhaps a bit faster although I would want to measure this in a real environment. That said, the question is about the design of the code.

Comment: go take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4922932/982161, after you get the point please open a chat room and we discuss the topic...

Comment: Then you may have missed the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4923029/1743880) (or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4922961/1743880)) in that linked question. And, still, the question is about improving the global design of the code.

Comment: the perf is out of topic here anyway, the PO asks for a more object oriented approach and I don't believe that a switch statement is real OO approach